# Google sheet script to export several ranges to pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

In google sheet I need a script to export several ranges to pdf. Each range should go to a new page of the pdf.
I know how to do it for one range, but then I don't know how to add the others.
My code is as follows:

```
function ExportPDF() 
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C14");

  var exportUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet.getId()
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=A4'                  //Tamaño del papel: 0-LETTER,1-TABLOID,2-LEGAL,3-STATEMENT,4-EXECUTIVE,5-FOLIO,6-A3,7-A4,8-A5,9-B4,10-B5
      + '&portrait=true'              //Orientación: False - Horizontal / True - Vertical
      + '&fitw=true'                   //Forzamos que quepa correctamente en el ancho de la hoja
      + '&top_margin=1'             //Margen Superior          
      + '&bottom_margin=1'          //Margen inferior         
      + '&left_margin=1'             //Margen Izquierdo          
      + '&right_margin=1'            //Margen Derecho        
      + '&sheetnames=false'            //Marcamos si se ha de poner el nombre de las hojas o no
      + '&printtitle=false'            //Marcamos si se ha imprimir el titulo del documento o no
      + '&pagenum=false'               //Indicamos si se de pintar el número de página
      + '&gridlines=false'              //Marcamos si queremos que se vean las lineas de las celdas o no   
      + '&fzr=FALSE'                   //Frozen: marcamos si las cabeceras se han de ir imprimiendo o no en las consecutivas hojas
      + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //Identificador del tab
      + '&r1=' + (range.getRow() - 1)  //Margenes del rango seleccionado
      + '&r2=' + range.getLastRow()
      + '&c1=' + (range.getColumn() - 1)
      + '&c2=' + range.getLastColumn();
       
  //Hacemos la petición para pedir el PDF
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {  muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()  } } );
  
  //Creamos el PDF con el binario que nos devuelve la petición anterior
  var blob = response.getBlob();
  blob = blob.setName(spreadsheet.getName());
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(pdfFile.getUrl());
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

I was able to get the above code to work

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I need a script to export to pdf several ranges of different sheets.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: My English is very bad and maybe the title is bad written, I am going to rewrite it.
I need a script to export several ranges from my google spreadsheet to pdf

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: You want to export "several ranges". Would you please edit your question to provide details of the specific ranges that you want to export. This should include the Sheet Name (unless each range is on the active sheet) and the the various data ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
The ranges are on different sheets of the same active spreadsheet, the exact names do not matter.
I was able to solve it in another way:
I create a google doc with marks in the text, with google script I replace the marks by values of the ranges in the spreadsheet and then export the doc to pdf .

I still have the doubt if I could have solved it in the other way.